# Rename nodes like xsi:type="xxx" in XML

Tags: xml

i have to rename all nodes named like `nodename xsi:type="subname"`
for example:
`<ProjectChild xsi:type="Group">` rename to `<ProjectChildGroup>`
and the Endtag tag `</ProjectChild">` also rename to `</ProjectChildGroup>`

Problem: Nodes have the same name inside a nested structure
`<ProjectChild xsi:type="Group">` and
`<ProjectChild xsi:type="Position">`

i have no plan, how to do that

My XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Project xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Children>
        <ProjectChild xsi:type="Group"> <----RENAME TO GROUP----
          <Number>1</Number>
          <Name>Malerarbeiten</Name>
          <children>
            <ProjectChild xsi:type="Position"> <----RENAME TO POSITION----
              <Number>1</Number>
              <Name>Wand Bestand</Name>
              <CalculationItems>
                <CalculationItem xsi:type="PointCalculationItem"> <----RENAME TO ..Item----
                  <Name>Bestand mit Tapete</Name>
                  <Comment />
                  <Count>1</Count>
                  <Area>98.8487577533343</Area>
                  <AreaFormula>plo * h = (5,81+19,68+5,435+0,08+0,375) * 3,15</AreaFormula>
                  <Sign>1</Sign>
                </CalculationItem>
              </CalculationItems>
              <Value>185.713</Value>
              <ValueFormula>185,713</ValueFormula>
              <Unit>m²</Unit>
            </ProjectChild> <----RENAME TO POSITION----
            <ProjectChild xsi:type="Position">
              <Number>2</Number>
              <Name>Ziegelwand</Name>
             ...
            </ProjectChild>
          </children>
        </ProjectChild> <----RENAME TO GROUP----
        <ProjectChild xsi:type="Group">
              ...
    </ProjectChild>
   </Children>
  <Name>SG H5-1.OG</Name>
</Project>
```

Comment: You can do this with DOM manipulation (ie in C#, Java, Node.js) or XSL.  What do you plan on using?

Comment: Put in dataSet —> datagridview, Filter and select —>Printout with dgvprinter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very simple XSLT transformation, basically an identity transformation with one added template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@xsi:type]">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}{@xsi:type}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! After build a xslt stylsheet and run this modifications, i was able to read the xml in a dataset

Answer (score 0):

here may solution:

1. build xslt/stylesheet
2. run modifications

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>     
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
         <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    
        <xsl:template match="*[@xsi:type]">
         <xsl:element name="{name()}{@xsi:type}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
        
        <xsl:template match="Column[@SourceColumn='points']|points" />
        <xsl:template match="Column[@SourceColumn='Sources']|Sources" />
        <xsl:template match="Column[@SourceColumn='CalculationSource']|CalculationSource" />
        <xsl:template match="Column[@SourceColumn='Sign']|Sign" />
        <xsl:template match="Column[@SourceColumn='VolumeFormula']|VolumeFormula" />
        <xsl:template match="Column[@SourceColumn='Volume']|Volume" />
        <xsl:template match="Column[@SourceColumn='Variables']|Variables" />
            
    </xsl:stylesheet>

2. run the modification

    XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(filename);
    System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform();
    myXslTrans.Load(myStyleSheet);
    myXslTrans.Transform(filename, outputXML);
```